# Am i using ifstream::fail() method in bad way?

Tags: c++

I have the txt file which contains for example:

```
Arthur 20

Mark 21

Josh 12
```

**The are no empty lanes between, its only for readability!**

What I want to do is write it on the screen in the same way as it is in the file.

I tried to make it this way:

```
ifstream file;
string word;

file.open("data.txt");
while(!file.eof()){

    file >> word;

    if(file.fail())
    break;

    cout << word << " ";
    file >> word;
    cout << word << endl;
}
```

But the output is:

```
Arthur 20

Mark 21

Josh 12

0
```

So why this 0 is being caught as a empty line to my string variable? I thought that fail() should stop the loop and leave me with correct output?

Comment: Related [Why is iostream::eof inside a loop condition considered wrong?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5605125/why-is-iostreameof-inside-a-loop-condition-considered-wrong)

Comment: Also, your loop condition is checking `data`, but youre reading from `file`?

Comment: data.txt is just the name of text file which is handled by data variable.

Comment: `while(!data.eof()){` <--- this is the file name? that does not make much sense

Comment: Oh crap, You're right. I edited

Comment: Anyways can i use any method to do this? I remember that someway i did it few months ago when using the fail() method.

Comment: I mean the solution in the post you looks like fixes problem only for disposable read.

Comment: if open succeeds then the body of while is executed then checking again inside loop for opening is bad thing and redundant. there's an alternative to this: `while( getline(file,  word ) ){
    cout << word << endl;
}`

Comment: Sure, but here i have the name and integer for age for example.

Comment: I mean I want to get Name for string, then get age to the same string. But all these should be at one iteration.

Comment: ok then read the first as a string and the second as an integer

Comment: But can't i read the number as a string? I want to use one string variable only.

Comment: `string word; int age; while( file >> word)
 {
  file >> age;
  cout << word << "   " << age << endl;
 }`

Comment: Yeah, i know. But I'm wondering if i can use only this one "word" variable to read word AND age.

Comment: Why do you want to use only one variable?

Comment: Why use two if i can do it with one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as long as you have names which don't contain white spaces and age as integer then you can read name as a string and age as an integer.

you don't need to check whether the file was successfully opened or not you can just abbreviate the operation:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>


int main()
{

    std::ifstream file;
    std::string   word;
    int age;

    file.open("data.txt");

    while( file >> word)
    {
        file >> age;
        std::cout << word << "   " << age << std::endl;
    }


    std::cout << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

- if you want to use one variable and for sure a string one then:

  ```
  while( file >> word)
  {
      std::cout << word << "   ";
      file >> word;
      std::cout << word << std::endl;
  }
  ```

I don't see any good thing to read age as a string and maybe later convert it back to an integer!

the output:

```
Arthur   20
Mark   21
Josh   12
```